# GWT with MVP: How to communicate between 2 views?

Tags: gwt, view, mvp, presenter

i use the MVP-Pattern in GWT.
I have developed a GWT-TabPanel. Each Tab has his own Presenter and his own view. But now i want to use some Datas from ViewX in ViewY.

Is there a simple way to realize it?

Greetz

Comment: Is there a reason this question was voted down???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use [EventBus](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html) to communicate between different views. See more about using EventBus and events in this article - [Large scale application development and MVP](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html#events).